# gcc optimize busy waiting as dead loop

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc

I'm implementing a single-producer single-consumer queue, by which one thread waits for the global queue to be filled by another thread like this:

```
while (queue.head == queue.tail);
```

When I compiled the program will gcc -O0, it worked well. But when it was compiled with gcc -O1, deadloop happened. Then I looked into assembly code and found that the latter version checked (queue.head == queue.tail) only once, if it was not true, then jumped to a dead loop and never checked again.

I also tried to declare queue as volatile but it didn't work. How to make gcc aware that queue is shared among threads and stop optimizing like that? Many thanks.

P.S.

1 In a single-threaded program, it is OK to optimize like that. But in my program queue.tail can be modified by another thread.

2 My queue was declared like this:

```
typedef struct {
    struct my_data data[MAX_QUEUE_LEN];
    int head;
    int tail;
} my_queue_t;

volatile my_queue_t queue;
```

3 I've also tried to declare head and tail (but not the whole struct) as volatile, it didn't work. But after I declare queue, head, tail all as volatile, it works. So is volatile should be declared to all the related variables like this?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "deadloop happened"?

Anyway, why *should* it check again? Your code says to continue the loop as long as they're equal. If it is not true, it will end the loop, because that's what you asked it to do.

Comment: Could you show the definition of queue... including how you tried declaring them volatile.

Comment: I don't know whether I am making sense..but is this code supposed to work only on a multi-processor system where you will wait in the loop while an instruction executes in the other processor which makes this loop to break..something like a spin count?? is that the reason why you trying to make it volatile?

Comment: please don't try to use HTML tags to format your code - use the 1010 button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I compiled the following code:

```
struct my_data {
    int x;
};

typedef struct {
    struct my_data data[5];
    int head;
    int tail;
} my_queue_t;

volatile my_queue_t queue;

int main() {
    while (queue.head == queue.tail);
}
```

with :

```
g++ -S -c -O1  th.cpp
```

which (for the while loop) produced the folowing output:

```
       movl    $_queue+20, %edx
       movl    $_queue+24, %eax
L2:
       movl    (%edx), %ebx
       movl    (%eax), %ecx
       cmpl    %ecx, %ebx
       je      L2
```

where the head and tail are loaded & tested inside the loop. Could you post what assembler you are getting emitted?

**Edit:** Making head and tail volatile in the struct declaration, rather than declaring the struct instance volatile, resulted in identical code.

Comment: I'm sorry that it was my mistake to regard volatile declaration as no use, I changed that declearation in a header file which was not included as a dependency in makefile, so the code change just wasn't applied.

Comment: If you remove the volatile declarations, does the loop get optimized away?

Comment: No, the loop remains but the comparison only takes place once.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried declaring head/tail as volatile?